# struts2 s:radio cssClass and cssStyle add attribute twice

Tags: css, struts2, attributes, radio-button

I would put my JSP file in HTML5 format.

I have a problem with the tag struts radio button;

when I put cssclass"disabled" ( or other like cssClass"red" ) , when I look the source I get twice attribute class="disabled".
But It works nice for the other struts tag.

See example below:

JSP file:

> `<s:radio cssClass="disabled" name="mirror.swiBlo"  list="Y"/>`

source:

```
<input type="radio" name="mirror.swiBlo" id="consultation_mirror_swiBloY" value="Y"    class="disabled" class="disabled"/>
```

If someone has any idea to solve that.

Thanks

Comment: What if you use a class named `disabl3d` ? What if you use `simple` theme instead of the default one ?

Comment: This `list="Y"` looks like invalid list. Show the real code.

Comment: The real code is : list="#{@com.mirror.struts.Constants@YES:''}"    And  the default theme is 'simple' for me. I'm looking for if this tag pass through two flt and not only in radiomap.ftl

Comment: What if you use a class named `disabl3d` (or `foo` )?

Answer (score 0):

Actually it's a bug in struts.

In `simple/radiomap.ftl` setting of class and style occurs twice.

source code:

```
<#if parameters.cssClass??>
 class="${parameters.cssClass?html}"<#rt/>
</#if>
<#if parameters.cssStyle??>
 style="${parameters.cssStyle?html}"<#rt/>
</#if>
<#include "/${parameters.templateDir}/simple/css.ftl" />
```

And `css.ftl` handle class and style again.